# Am trying to connect to Jamovi from R Studio and I get the error: Error: No such file or directory. All paths correctly specified

Tags: r, rstudio, jamovi

Am trying to connect to Jamovi from R Studio and facing the following problem. Am unable to read from Jamovi. Have loaded:

```
library(jmvcore)
library(jmv)
library(jmvconnect)
library(jmvReadWrite)

jmvconnect::what()
```

gives me the file index and name.

But when I do:

```
Data <- jmvconnect::read(1)
```

returns Error: No such file or directory. All paths have been correctly specified.

And when I tried the other library: jmvReadWrite:

```
Data <- read_omv(fileInp = "xxxx full path to .omv file",
                      rmMsVl = TRUE,
                      sveAtt = TRUE,
                      getSyn = TRUE
                  )
```

gives me

Error in read_omv(fileInp = "xxxx full path to .omv file",  :
unused argument (fileInp = "xxxx full path to .omv file")

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: could this be just a typo? The documentation of `read_omv` specifies the argument `fleInp` not `fileInp`: https://sjentsch.github.io/jmvReadWrite/reference/read_omv.html

Comment: Thanks for the sharp eye. It was a typo indeed. Had my spectacles changed once again only today! THe issue with : Data <- jmvconnect::read(1) remains.